# Google Play services out of date. Requires 10084000 but found 8118436

Tags: android, google-play-services, genymotion

I'm trying to run Google Play Services on my Android emulator using Genymotion. I followed the steps in another Stack Overflow to download and install ARM Translation Installer and the Google Apps for my Android version (5.1.0). Up until this point, there doesn't seem to be any issues.

The issue occurs when I open my development app and try to connect to Google Play Services. I see `Google Play services out of date. Requires 10084000 but found 8118436`.

I know that this means the version of my emulator is 8.1 and the version that is being bundled is 10.0. However, I don't know how to make these two versions the same. I can't figure out how to either downgrade one, or update the other. Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: try using lower version of google play services in your build dependecy may be 9.6 or any other 9.x version

Comment: @Shubham Do you have a source confirming that Google Play Services build dependency version has any influence on the version required on the client side?

Comment: @Shubham Thanks for the comment. I've added `compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:9.6.0"` (I want only Google Fit) to my dependencies, but when I try to run my app I see "Installing APK" and it's incredibly slow - I question if it's moving at all. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: On the Genymotion emulator, try updating your Google Play Services - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out this issue. For those having the same problem, you need to download the correct APK. Go here to find it: http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/